# The label 'T14' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, text, varchar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpazU.png)Incorrect syntax near '<'.

The label 'T14' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

The code follows:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML

SELECT @XML = XMLData   
FROM ReadXmlFile
WHERE IndexRow = @IndexRow;

Declare @Str Varchar(max)
SET @Str=(select cast(@XML as varchar(max)))

EXEC(@Str)
PRINT(@Str)
```

table ReadXmlFile is contains 3 column (IndexRow,XmlData,DateTime) that value of XmlData is filled by the user uploaded file

and @Str in Old StoredProcedure was:

```
Declare @Str Varchar(1000)
SET @Str='BULK INSERT #tbltest1
FROM ''//192.168.1.20/Softwares/' + @stfName + '/Reading/' + @FILE_NAME + '''
WITH
(
     DATAFILETYPE =''char'',
     Rowterminator=''\n''
     --firstrow=10
)'
```

now i want #tbltest1 in part `**SET @Str='BULK INSERT #tbltest1**` fill by column **XmlData** from table ReadXmlFile **Instead** Fill by the following **path** '//192.168.1.20/Softwares/' + @stfName + '/Reading/' + @FILE_NAME +

this is part of the file XML:

```
<TestUniverseExport xmlns="http://www.omicron.at/dataexport">
  <TM_Common>
    <TestReportID>c522187c-2175-4b84-90b3-ebb6f854694c</TestReportID>
    <TestReportOrder>1</TestReportOrder>
    <Name>OMICRON Advanced Distance</Name>
    <Version>2.40 </Version>
    <Title>REL521-DE805.adt</Title>
    <TestStartDate>1394-08-03T14:00:20+04:30</TestStartDate>
    <TestEndDate>1394-08-03T14:02:45+04:30</TestEndDate>
    <Offline>false</Offline>
    <Overload>false</Overload>
    <HWCReportOrder>0</HWCReportOrder>
    <TOReportOrder>0</TOReportOrder>
    <Assessment>PASSED</Assessment>
    <ManualAssessment>false</ManualAssessment>
    <PartiallyExecuted>false</PartiallyExecuted>
    <Error>false</Error>
    <TestStartMode>IMMEDIATELY</TestStartMode>
  </TM_Common>
  <TM_Dist>
    <TestReportID>c522187c-2175-4b84-90b3-ebb6f854694c</TestReportID>
    <TestReportOrder>1</TestReportOrder>
    <TestModel>CONSTANT_CURRENT</TestModel>
```

Comment: Check your ReadXmlFile or the original XML file and check how many times T14 appears.

Comment: No way to tell without seeing your data, but similar errors can occur when you forget to quote a guid.

Comment: "T14" is obviously your date... maybe it needs to be quoted or similar.

Comment: As shnugo said - you cannot execute XML as a tsql statement. No one knows what you are trying to do though some have guessed. I suggest you discuss this with your coworkers.

Comment: I think, as you are trying to **execute** the XML, as if this was a dynamically created statement, the engine gives its best to parse the statement and finds `T14:` This look like a code label, something you might want to jump at with a [GOTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)...

Answer (score 1):

What you show us, is not enough to answer your question properly. I must admit, I do not even see a question... And I doubt, that the message you get is really connected to this `T14` within your dateTimes...

Your XML is - after adding some closing tags - perfectly okay:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<TestUniverseExport>
    <TM_Common>
        <TestReportID>c522187c-2175-4b84-90b3-ebb6f854694c</TestReportID> 
        <TestReportOrder>1</TestReportOrder>
        <Name>OMICRON Advanced Distance</Name>
        <Version>2.40 </Version>
        <Title>REL521-DE805.adt</Title>
        <TestStartDate>1394-08-03T14:00:20+04:30</TestStartDate> 
        <TestEndDate>1394-08-03T14:02:45+04:30</TestEndDate>
    </TM_Common>
</TestUniverseExport>';

SELECT elmnts.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS ElementName
      ,elmnts.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ElementValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/TestUniverseExport/TM_Common/*') A(elmnts);
```

There must be something within the data, which brings up this error. Is `XMLData` a natively typed XML column?

And it is totally unclear what you are trying to get here:

```
Declare @Str Varchar(max)
SET @Str=(select cast(@XML as varchar(max)))
EXEC(@Str)
```

This is rather weird... Casting a XML to a string type will not result in an executable SQL-command...

Please try to add to your question and - if possible - provide a MCVE, to reproduce your issue.

## UPDATE: After you edited your quesiton...

From the screenshot I take, that the table contains XML-typed values. And you try to change the old code in a way, that the XML is not taken from a file any more but directly out of that table. Correct so far?

If my assumptions are correct, this might be really trivial:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML;

SELECT @XML = XMLData   
FROM ReadXmlFile
WHERE IndexRow = @IndexRow;

Declare @Str Varchar(max);
SET @Str=cast(@XML as varchar(max));
```

The old code needed the dynamically created statement (together with `EXEC()` and `PRINT`) to load the XML from the file system. But now you have the XML directly in your table. So just take it, cast it and proceed from there...

What your own attempts did, was to execute something which was not a SQL-Command by any means...

Comment: In the old way, the information is poured into the **#tbltest1** table and then the @Test table as follows is filled in by the **#tbltest1** table   
`Declare @Test table(ID int Identity(1,1),coulm varchar(100))
insert into @Test select * from #tbltest1`
                                                    
But in my new method, how do I the @Xml information in a column with multiple rows into the #tbltest1 table؟
And I used the Convert method and the Cast method with the max value, but I had an error because of the large file size

Comment: this is old way :

`Declare @Str Varchar(1000)
SET @Str='BULK INSERT #tbltest1
FROM ''//192.168.1.20/Softwares/' + @FILE_NAME + '''
WITH
(
     DATAFILETYPE =''char'',
  Rowterminator=''\n''
  --firstrow=10
)'

EXEC(@Str)


Declare @Test table(ID int Identity(1,1),coulm varchar(100))

insert into @Test select * from #tbltest1`

Answer (score 0):

You are executing an invalid `sql` query. See on how to use sql [exec | execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Wrap your query with the correct strings.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML
SELECT @XML = XMLData   
  FROM ReadXmlFile
  WHERE IndexRow = @IndexRow;

Declare @Str Varchar(max)
SET @Str='select '''+cast(@XML as varchar(max))+''''

EXEC(@Str)
PRINT(@Str)
```

or if you want to view it as `xml`.

```
 SET @Str='select cast('''+cast(@XML as varchar(max))+''' as xml)'
```